# How do I install IMDbPY on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, imdb

I would like to start using [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/?page=main) but I can't find a Windows installer on their site. What is the most simple way to install it? Is there a way to install it using my Python interpreter?

Comment: Download -> Unofficial Packages -> Microsoft Windows (installer for Python 2.7): IMDbPY-win32-py2.7-4.7.exe -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/imdbpy/files/IMDbPY/4.7/IMDbPY-win32-py2.7-4.7.exe/download

Comment: Also checkout http://code.activestate.com/pypm/imdbpy/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Windows installer](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/imdbpy/IMDbPY-win32-py2.7-4.7.exe?download)

[Python installer](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/imdbpy/IMDbPY-4.7.tar.gz) - run `python -O setup.py install`